# Opening with Excel without saving file permanently with Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache Poi to create an Excel file from a JTable.

I want to open the file directly in Excel, rather than first write it to disk and then open it from the disk.

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( StolleExcel.xls" );
workBook.write( output );

Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.open( new File( "StolleExcel.xls" ) );

output.close();
```

Is there a temporary way of saving the Excel object then just opening it with Excel, so the user can save or edit whatever they want?